# trying to re-write url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to change the way my url looks as it looks really messy

iv been trying to work out mod-rewrite in my .htaccess file

here's my url :http://www.blablabla.com/user_poll_profile.php?user_id=212

i basicaly just want: blablabla.com/user

and here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

is it possible to atcheive the url i want????
or am i even close????

i have look at about a million different tut's and forums but none work:(

any help would be great

Kind regards 
Ronan

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them work"? What _exactly_? Do you get an error? Do you get a blank page? Does the universe explode?

Comment: Does that .htaccess file get processed at all? Is support for .htaccess files enabled? What if you put a syntax error in it. is it ignored or do you get an error message pointing towards that syntax error? Can you enable Rewrite Logging?

Comment: Your current code makes no real sense at all. I also have trouble understanding your question. Am I correct if I say that you want the url /user/212 to show what /user_poll_profile.php?user_id=212 does now?

Answer (score 0):

When using a rewrite rule like this, the first part of the rule should reflect what you want typed in the address bar, and the second part should be the location of where the actual file is.

In this case you want to type in www.domain.com/user/212, and that should show the contents of www.domain.com/user_poll_profile.php?user_id=212 right? Then this is the way you should handle that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ /user_poll_profile.php?user_id=$1 [L]
```

This only rewrites the user URL though. If you have more urls that work like this you will need to change the code a bit. That totally depends on the urls you want and the underlying structure of the php files so it's hard to give a more generic answer right now.

Comment: Big thanks Stephan, this is what i was looking for, iv changed my .htacces file and uploaded it to the server...should this hav an imediate effect???....still no changes...

Comment: PROBLEM server run on Zeus NOT Apache??????any idea how to set it up for Zeus????

Comment: Hmm no, never heard of that.